Hyper-V Guest in TrueNAS
I'm working with TrueNAS-SCALE-24.04.0 on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2123 CPU with 126 GiB of memory, attempting to import and run a Hyper-V exported VM for backup purposes. The VM is in VHDX format. My goal isn't necessarily optimal performance; I primarily need to ensure the VM boots up and is accessible.
So far, I've attempted to convert the VHDX image to a ZVol on TrueNAS. However, creating a new KVM instance from this has led to multiple cascading issues, including system and networking problems, among other errors that arise from just converting and attaching the VM.
Given the numerous issues, I'm considering other strategies, perhaps using my existing Windows 11 VM on TrueNAS as a Hyper-V host, although I'm aware virtualization isn't enabled by default on TrueNAS.
Has anyone successfully imported and run a Hyper-V guest on TrueNAS SCALE? What strategies or tools did you use? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Hyper-V exported VM Are you talking about a Windows guest?

I am referring to the ability to perform nested virtualization.

I know. I thought you haven't given up on the original approach, based on the fact that you asked at the end: Has anyone successfully imported and run a Hyper-V guest on TrueNAS SCALE?.

It's definitely not impossible to have "Hyper-V on KVM", but whether one can get it done, well you know, it always depends on "this and that". (Just like while you have bumped into multiple cascading issues, including system and networking problems, among other errors, it doesn't mean that no one could and would take them down one by one.)

You can use nested virtualization on TrueNAS Scale. Check for more information: https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/can-i-run-vmware-on-truenas-nested.101505/
You should be aware that nested virtualization has a big performance overhead. Nested is good for testing, but not for running production 24/7. You can convert VHDX to qcow2 and then convert qcow2 to zvol to use it as VM on TrueNAS, without a need to use nested virtualization.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConverttoQCOW2.html
https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/kvm-not-recognizing-disks-in-qcow2-format-truenas-scale.94609/

I have come across information stating that TrueNAS does not support nested virtualization.

Where did you read about it?
